# Least squares problem: am I solving it correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

So I have this question:

> In $\mathbb R^3$ with inner product calculate all the least square solutions, and choose the one with shorter length, of the system:
>   $ x + y + z = 1 $
>   $ x + z = 0 $
>   $ y = 0 $

My attempt: So I applied the formula $ A^T A x = A^T b $ with A as being the matrix with row 1 (1,1,1) row 2 (1,0,1) and row 3 (0,1,0); x being the column $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and b being the column (1,0,0).

So I did it and I reached to the solution $(x_1, \frac {1}{3}, \frac {1}{3} + x_1)$

And I expanded this solution in two vectors $(0, \frac {1}{3}, \frac {1}{3}) $ and $(1,0,1)$.

So these are the least square solutions and the one with shorter length is the first one.

My doubt is if I'm doing this correctly or if I made any mistake because I used an online calculator that only give one least square solution. Can someone help me to verify my attempt? Thanks!

Comment: Trick question: the system is inconsistent (if I'm understanding correctly)

Comment: Isn't that the point of using least squares?

Comment: OK, I think I'm misunderstanding the question. To me, least squares means you are given fewer equations than variables and you have to maximize some sort of function within those constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The reduced row echelon form is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &\mapsto \mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{A}} \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
&\mapsto
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$
There is a rank defect of $1$. Row 1 = row 2 + row 3.

The linear system is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} x &= b \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
 z
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The least squares solution is resolved to $\color{blue}{range}$ and $\color{red}{null}$ space components
$$
\begin{align}
  x_{LS} &= 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b} + 
\color{red}{\left( \mathbf{I}_{3} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A} \right) \xi} \\
%
&=
%
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{6}
\left[
\begin{array}{crr}
 1 & 2 & -1 \\
 2 & -2 & 4 \\
 1 & 2 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right]}
%
+ 
%
\color{red}{
\frac{1}{2}
\left[
\begin{array}{rcr}
 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right] \xi}, \quad \xi \in \mathbf{C}^{n}  \\[3pt]
%
&=
\color{blue}{
 \frac{1}{6}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  2 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]}
+
\color{red}{
 \alpha
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\
  0 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]}, \quad \alpha \in \mathbb{C}
%
\end{align}
$$
where $\xi$ is an arbitrary vector in the domain $\mathbb{C}^{3}$.

The residual error vector is
$$
\color{red}{r} =   \mathbf{A} \color{blue}{x_{LS}} - b = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\
  1 \\
  0
\end{array}
\right]},
$$
and the total error is $r^{2} = \frac{2}{9}.$